# Android phone APP updated but not all getting the update

Tags: android, updates

we had updated our APP 10 days ago and many current users can't get the auto-update but some are updated automatically. Even for the new download, some are getting the latest updated version at Google Playstore but some are getting the older version. Anyone can help to solve this? Is this the phone issue or is there a bug?

Comment: you have increased requirements in new version (higher min. SDK, requirement for the device to have bluetooth, made app unavailable for large screen devices, or 100 more reasons.) So you have to compare manifest files of old and new apps

Comment: Do you have a staged rolled out or a full one? With a stages rolled out only a percentage of user will have access to it.